# Are these files safe to delete on Android?

Tags: internal-storage

Whilst I was deleting files on my Android to clear up some space; I came across two strange files. One was PubmetricinstalledList and the other was PubmetricmoreApps. The first file contained two separate files which were a .str file and a .tss file. The second file had many folders with all titled with three number ranging from 500 to 900 and inside of them were folders with more random numbers, and inside those folders were two files which were a .ibm file and an .jsn file.

Does anyone know what these files are, and if so are they safe to delete? Sorry for my bad explanation I am mostly curious on what these files are since I couldn't find anything online about them. Thanks!

Comment: All files under /sdcard aka Internal Storage are fully disposable without a risk to system stability.