# What data can I delete to clear up space?

Tags: cleanup

I am confused as to what data I can delete without losing valuable files or screwing up my system processes.

Comment: Related: [Are these files safe to delete on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233870/are-these-files-safe-to-delete-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

Android by default won't let you delete system files. So do not worry.

IMHO, the first step to free up storage, would be to uninstall your unnecessary apps, followed by deleting old/not required media files like images or videos. These are the main storage consuming parts as such.